# How can I change the MAC address of a network bridge in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, dhcp, bridge, mac-address

I use DHCP reservation rather than static IP for convenience, and that relies on the MAC address of my computer.

I recently bridged my main adapter with my VirtualBox adapter.  When things stopped working, I realized that the MAC address is now different.  Is there some way to keep it the same every time I bridge or unbridge or do I need to reconfigure the router every time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the MAC Address of a network adapter manually:

Open the Registry Editor:

Navigate to the folowing key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

Go through the numbered subkeys until you find one that matches your network adapter configuration. Modify the value named `NetworkAddress` to reflect the desired MAC address, but without hyphens/colons, if you want `00-B3-A0-03-00-1F`, set the value to `00B3A003001F`.

It's possible that `NetworkAddress` may not exist, if so - create the key as a `'New' -> 'String Value'`.

Once that's done, you need to disable/enable the network adapter in the Network Connections settings page for the change to take effect.

[Reference to original article is here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120602092102/http://www.windowsreference.com:80/networking/how-to-change-mac-address-in-windows-registry)

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Good point jscott, let me clear this mess up

Comment: @jscott Better? :-)

Comment: Yes, much actually and +1.